# See or retrieve a Core Data .sqlite file from a device

Tags: ios, core-data

How can I actually get to see the .sqlite file for the Core Data store on a real device (not simulator)? Are there tools that allow you see the Core Data information?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Xcode:

1. Open the Devices window (shift-cmd-2)
2. Select your device from the list on the left
3. Select your app from the "Installed Apps" list
4. Click the gear icon at the bottom of the "Installed Apps" list
5. Select "Download container"
6. Save the container somewhere
7. Xcode will open the container location in under.  Ctrl-click on the container and select "Show package contents"
8. You can now open the documents folder and see your app's files.