# Location of the sqlite data store

Tags: ios, sqlite, xcode8

I've read many post on how to locate the data store, but am still unable to find it.

I'm printing the location of the Container when I create my Persistent Container:

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "DataModel")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: {
            storeDescription, error in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Could load data store: \(error)")
            }
        })
        print(container.persistentStoreDescriptions)**
        return container
    }()
```

The output is as follows:

[`<NSPersistentStoreDescription: 0x174245190> (type: SQLite, url: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CF77409C-0CD7-4F4F-B657-831E4FA4544B/Library/Application%20Support/DataModel.sqlite)]`

I find the Mac file system very confusing.  When I go to finder and select Go -> Go to folder... What do I paste as the path?

Thanks.

Comment: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CF77409C-0CD7-4F4F-B657-831E4FA4544B/Library/Application Support/

Comment: Hey shallowThought, Thanks but I've done that and I brought to the var directory just under the Macintosh HD... which I guess is the drive itself.  What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes. I thought you are on the simulator. You can not reach the device using Finder's GO feature. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43402673/1457385) might help.

Comment: Could you expound on that please?  All of the Project files are stored on the Mac.  Where else would they be.  Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Please add tag(s) for your target system (iOS, macOS ...).

Comment: Sorry.. iOS.  Will add tag now.

Comment: As you are developing for iOS, the .sqlite file is either in the simulators directory (default "Documents" dir) or on the device. Your path looks like you are on a real device.
You can not reach a (non-jailbroken) device through Finder.
You can down(and up)load data from the device through Xcode: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26007804/1457385